# Adding text at a position relative to a specific word

Tags: java, itext

I have a PDF document with a text like "**Approver Name** ". This is Unique and appears only once.

I'm trying to put a image just to the right side of the text "Approver Name" . I was able to insert image using below. But i need to put this on right side of "**Approve Name**" text. What is the way to get the position of this text and keep the image next to that text.

```
  Image img = Image.getInstance(RESOURCE);
        img.setAbsolutePosition(
            (PageSize.POSTCARD.getWidth() - img.getScaledWidth()) / 2,
            (PageSize.POSTCARD.getHeight() - img.getScaledHeight()) / 2);
        document.add(img);
```

Comment: When you talk about "a field", it is assumed that you are referring to "an AcroForm field". Do you know the name of that field?

Comment: Its actually a simple Text in PDF and not AcroForm field

Comment: That makes it very difficult (maybe even impossible) to give you a simple answer. Is there any way you can mark this *field that isn't actually a field*? Can you add a form field or an annotation to the template?

Comment: Actually the PDF will be dynamically generated from word document and then i need to manipulate the PDF. So basically its not a PDF template so i don't have control on it to add annotation or field..It certainly looks strange but just wondering what are the other options regarding this case..

Comment: People have done this in the past by adding specific anchors in the Word document. Anchors that result in either an annotation or a bookmark in the PDF. The coordinates of those anchors are then used to add extra content, after which the anchors are removed. Depending on some hard coded word is not a good idea.

Comment: Thanks for your help Bruno..i will try these options

Comment: OK, experiment with Word to PDF and use iText RUPS to inspect what's added inside the PDF (normally, you'll add some coordinates that will be visible under the hood). Once you've made a choice, we can further help you explaining what's the best way to retrieve these coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

> What is the way to get the position of this text and keep the image
>   next to that text.

Why not ask Stackoverflow these two questions?

- [Searching words in PDF and Extracting it using iText in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12938397/searching-words-in-pdf-and-extracting-it-using-itext-in-android)
- [Is it possible to find text position with iText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5326496/is-it-possible-to-find-text-position-with-itext)

Comment: After having received clarification about the nature of the *field*, these are actually good pointers. Sure: it's not a full-blown answer, but the question is problematic too.